# Table don't have primary key still getting an error related to primary key

Tags: sql, linq-to-entities

**Description:**

I'm inserting data to a table which don't have primary key, but still I'm getting **"Saving or accepting changes failed because more than one entity of type X.Y.daDataAccessQueries' have the same primary key value.**" this error while inserting duplicate records in table.  Please help to find the reason behind this.

**Code:**

```
var accessQuery = new daDataAccessQueries();
                    accessQuery.partitionKey = partitionKey;
                    accessQuery.queryKey = rowKey;


                    daDataAccess entry = db.daDataAccess.Single(o => o.daId == profileId);
                    entry.daDataAccessQueries.Add(accessQuery)
```

This entry.daDataAccessQueries.Add(accessQuery) is throwing an exception.

Comment: *table which don't have primary key* that's a really bad table structure.You should change the design and add a primary key for your table.

Comment: Perhaps although your table doesn't have a primary key, the LINQ to SQL class thinks it does?  In any case, without seeing any sort of data it is impossible to properly diagnose your problem.

Comment: In Entity Framwork, every entity has a key, defined either by convention (if it's called `id` or maybe other special words), by a fluent model definition or by attributes. If a key wasn't properly defined, you'd get an exception on first model use. In particular, you can't possibly use EF to insert duplicate rows into any table. As @JibinBalachandran said, that's rarely appropriate, that's why EF doesn't support it.